# Транслятор с С# кода в код ассемблера х86

Tags: c#

В универе поставили задачу написать транслятор с С# языка на язык ассемблера(x86). Честно говоря ниразу в жизни даже не трогал ассемблер, а уже тем более не пытался писать на него транслятор. Как я понял моя прога должна получать на вход некоторый шарп код и показывать мне вариацию ассемблер кода. Мне казалось, что я смогу сделать это легко с помощью CodeDOM или Microsoft.CodeAnalysis(Roslyn) средствами генерации, а там не все так просто походу. В общем, если кто делал уже подобное, объясните вообще какие технологии гуглить, в каком направлении изучать этот вопрос.

Comment: Ого, «поставили задачу»? Пошлите их нафиг вот прямо сейчас. После чего подумайте, как вы будете реализовывать `dynamic` или `async`/`await`.

Comment: Задача немного проще, если вы будете транслировать из IL. Но снова-таки, вам придётся реализовать все интринсики наподобие `Monitor.Enter`. Это задача для коллектива программистов на год.

Comment: Ну послать не выйдет)), это экзаменационная задача...

Comment: Ну тогда это не к нам. Сохраните код и с ним сразу подавайтесь в Microsoft на serior'а.

Comment: дизморал. Понял буду искать дальше

Comment: Ну, вам поставили очень сложное задание, То есть реально сложное, я бы за него не взялся без очччень большого бонуса. И ещё непонятно, имеете ли вы право пользоваться стандартной библиотекой .NET или нет. (Например, нужно ли вам самостоятельно (!) писать сборщик мусора.)

Comment: Интересно, что за универ такой? MIT?